# How to configure SMTP for nopCommerce on smarterasp.net hosting using Yandex Mail for Domain?

Tags: email, smtp, web-hosting, nopcommerce, yandex

My app nopCommerce 3.70
MY host smarterasp.net
No SSL
I am going to use Yandex Mail for Domain for my app. (https://yandex.com/support/domain/chat.xml)

It used to work perfectly on arvixe.com hosting. 
arvixe.com: DNS - [10], mx.yandex.ru
nopCommerce: host - smtp.yandex.ru, port - 25, SSL - check, Use default credentials - LeaveItBlank.

Right away on smarterasp.net hosting I've got the problem:
Default - host - smtp.yandex.ru, port - 25, SSL - check, Use default credentials - LeaveItBlank.
Error - "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Yandes support service advised following settings: port - 465, SSL - check, Use default credentials - check Using them I get the error - "The operation has timed out."

Support smarterasp.net advised: "If the problem persists, you should contact your current email service provider to check their server log for you instead of us."

How to configure SMTP settings for nopCommerce on smarterasp.net hosting using Yandex Mail for Domain?

Comment: I have had similar problems with the mail mail.ru. it is necessary to use SSL, but at the same port must be specified 25. Try, if possible, specify an answer. [Link to russian SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466328/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-smtpclient-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/466372#466372)

Comment: With https://biz.mail.ru/ same problem.

Comment: With https://apps.google.com/intx/ru/ mail set up hoster (smarterasp.net), but to another domain

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried all ways.
With English not friends.
I can give you all the necessary approaches to address problemmy.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For Yandex;

```
Host: smtp.yandex.com
User: full mail address
Password: your password
Port: 587
SSL must be checked.
```